# Retornando componente dentro de uma função no react js

Tags: react

Fala pessoal, alguém consegue da um help nesta questão?

```
const LoadingHOC = (Component) =>{
    return class extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>Teste</h1>
                </div>
            )
        
            
        }
    }
}
export default LoadingHOC
```

Error: "react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Algo nao esta certo no seu codigo.
Voce está misturando um Class Component com um Funcional Conponent

Class Component

```
class LoadingHOC extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Teste</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default LoadingHOC;
```

Funtional Component

```
const LoadingHOC = () => (
    <div>
        <h1>Teste</h1>
    </div>
);
export default LoadingHOC;
```